# TriggerRemoteJob - Connection to remote server failed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have installed Jenkins in my local (https://localhost:8080) I tried `triggerRemoteJob-plugin`. I generated the below code using a snippet generator. The function call is failing with the below-shown error message.

What am I missing here?

```
triggerRemoteJob(
    // auth: NoneAuth(), - this also didn't work
    auth: TokenAuth(apiToken: '11xx90yycfxx77yy2dxxc9yy1bxx3cyy', userName: 'myuser'), 
    job: 'https://localhost:8080/job/dinesh-adhoc-script',
    remoteJenkinsUrl: 'https://localhost:8080', 
    token: 'build-trigger-token',
    maxConn: 1,
    overrideTrustAllCertificates: true,
    trustAllCertificates: true
)
```

Error Message:

```
Parameterized Remote Trigger Configuration:
    - job:                     https://localhost:8080/job/dinesh-adhoc-script 
    - remoteJenkinsUrl:        https://localhost:8080
    - auth:                    'Token Authentication' as user 'myuser'
    - parameters:              
    - blockBuildUntilComplete: true
    - connectionRetryLimit:    5
```

Connection to remote server failed, waiting for to retry - 10 seconds until next attempt.

URL: https://localhost:8080/job/dinesh-adhoc-script/api/json